# How to request fullscreen in compiled dart

Tags: dart, html5-fullscreen

I'm playing around with a Dart app trying to get fullscreen mode to work. My HTML (excluding boilerplate):

```
<div id="fullscreen_div">
  Clicking this should cause it to go fullscreen!
</div>
```

My Dart code:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var div = querySelector('#fullscreen_div');
  div.onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) {
    div.requestFullscreen();
    print('requested fullscreen');
  });
}
```

[Here it is on DartPad.](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3c0b9b112b5e8d79214a)

If I've done this correctly, clicking the div once should cause the div to go into fullscreen mode. On Chromium, this works. When compiled to JavaScript (both debug and minified), this does not happen, and the console outputs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This happens on both Chrome, Firefox and IE (tested on Windows 7). From what I've understood this is a common JavaScript error, and searching does not bring up anything obvious.

Any ideas why `requestFullScreen` won't work when dart is compiled to JS?

Comment: Some additional info https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4136&q=fullscreen&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified

Comment: Thanks for that @GünterZöchbauer, [this](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4136#c12) workaround worked for me. Is it okay to answer my own question with this info, or should I wait for someone else?

Comment: Totally OK to answer your own question. You have to wait some time anyway before you can accept it and if someone else comes up with a better solution later you can any time make another answer the accepted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments (thanks Günter!), this is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4136&q=fullscreen&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified). #12 in that thread posted a good workaround, edited by me to be a bit more generic:

```
import 'dart:js';
void fullscreenWorkaround(Element element) {
  var elem = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(element);

  if (elem.hasProperty("requestFullscreen")) {
    elem.callMethod("requestFullscreen");
  }
  else {
    List<String> vendors = ['moz', 'webkit', 'ms', 'o'];
    for (String vendor in vendors) {
      String vendorFullscreen = "${vendor}RequestFullscreen";
      if (vendor == 'moz') {
        vendorFullscreen = "${vendor}RequestFullScreen";
      }
      if (elem.hasProperty(vendorFullscreen)) {
        elem.callMethod(vendorFullscreen);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used this in my code, and replaced this call

```
div.requestFullscreen();
```

with

```
fullscreenWorkaround(div);
```

which worked great. Tested and working compiled on Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extended version of Tobbe hack to use the whole fullscreen API.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js';

// Workaround for https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4136
class FullscreenWorkaround {
  static void requestFullscreen(Element element) {
    _callMethods(element, [
      'requestFullscreen',
      'webkitRequestFullscreen',
      'mozRequestFullScreen',
      'msRequestFullscreen',
      'oRequestFullscreen'
    ]);
  }

  static void exitFullscreen() {
    _callMethods(document, [
      'exitFullscreen',
      'webkitExitFullscreen',
      'mozCancelFullScreen',
      'msExitFullscreen',
      'oExitFullscreen'
    ]);
  }

  static bool get fullscreenEnabled {
    var result = _getProperty(document, [
      'fullscreenEnabled',
      'webkitFullscreenEnabled',
      'mozFullScreenEnabled',
      'msFullscreenEnabled',
      'oFullscreenEnabled'
    ]);
    return result != null ? result : false;
  }

  static get fullscreenElement {
    return _getProperty(document, [
      'fullscreenElement',
      'webkitFullscreenElement',
      'mozFullScreenElement',
      'msFullscreenElement',
      'oFullscreenElement'
    ]);
  }

  static _callMethods(browserObject, List methods) {
    var jsElem = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(browserObject);

    for (String methodName in methods) {
      if (jsElem.hasProperty(methodName)) {
        return jsElem.callMethod(methodName);
      }
    }
  }

  static _getProperty(browserObject, List properties) {
    var jsElem = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(browserObject);

    for (String propertyName in properties) {
      if (jsElem.hasProperty(propertyName)) {
        return jsElem[propertyName];
      }
    }
  }
}
```