# Fullscreen and retrieving property by name in Dart

Tags: html, canvas, properties, dart

I'm working on making a HTML5 canvas fullscreen using Dart. Sadly every browser has another prefixed version of the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) and Dart doesn't keep track of it. Thus most of the time the methods provided by Dart don't work.
I found this "hack" to get going into fullscreen working perfectly fine:

```
JsObject canvasElement = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(_canvas);

List<String> methods = ["requestFullscreen", "mozRequestFullScreen", "webkitRequestFullscreen", "msRequestFullscreen"];
for(String method in methods){
  if(canvasElement.hasProperty(method)){
    canvasElement.callMethod(method);
    _canvas.width = window.screen.width;
    _canvas.height = window.screen.height;
    return;
  }
}
```

My problem is the following:
When pressing "Escape" or "F11" the fullscreen will be closed, but the canvas will not resize back to normal size. I tried to manually override the KeyDown event for this keys, but it seems that my browser (Google Chrome / Dartium) does not recognize the event in this special case...

Obviously I need to know, whether the browser is in fullscreen mode or not to resize the canvas accordingly. Is there a way to retrieve the javascript properties `document.fullscreenElement, document.webkitFullscreenElement, document.msFullscreenElement` as supposed in the [Fullscreen API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) in a similiar way like I could access the methods `document.requestFullscreen, document.webkitRequestFullscreen etc.` ?

Thank you very much for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I got it to work now. I am going to write an answer here, hence people having a similiar problem may find a solution:

You can access most of the vendor specific methods of the fullscreen API in dart like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751708/4618333). Moreover there is indeed a way to access properties if they exist as you can see in the lowest method of the code provided in the answer mentioned above...

I was right about the browser not throwing a keydown event, when pressing F11 or Esc to toggle fullscreen mode. I learned that this can be prevented by calling `event.preventDefault()` and then toggling fullscreen manually. The full sourcecode of my fullscreen management looks like this:

```
void init(){
    ....

    // initiate variables needed for fullscreen management
    _fullscreenTimer = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    _fullscreen = false;

    // setup event handler, thus pressing F11 toggles fullscreen
    window.onKeyDown.listen((KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.keyCode == KeyCode.F11) {
        // prevent going fullscreen without noticing
        e.preventDefault();

        // get current time
        int now = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

        // only toggle fullscreen when last toggle was at least 500ms before
        if ((now - _fullscreenTimer) >= 500) {
            // toggle fullscreen
            if (!_fullscreen) {
                _requestFullscreen();
            } else {
                _exitFullscreen();
            }

            // reset timer to current time
            _fullscreenTimer = now;
            }
        }
    });
}

void resize() {
    // the element currently in fullscreen mode
    var fullscreenElement = _getFullscreenElement();

    // check whether there was a change to or from fullscreen
    if (!_fullscreen && fullscreenElement != null) {
        _fullscreen = true;

        _canvas.width = window.screen.width;
        _canvas.height = window.screen.height;
    } else if (_fullscreen && fullscreenElement == null) {
        _fullscreen = false;

        _canvas.width = _originalWidth;
        _canvas.height = _originalHeight;
    }
}

/// requests fullscreen by calling the corresponding methods of each vendor
void _requestFullscreen() {
    _callMethods(_canvas, ['requestFullscreen', 'webkitRequestFullscreen', 'mozRequestFullScreen', 'msRequestFullscreen', 'oRequestFullscreen']);
}

/// exits fullscreen by calling the corresponding methods of each vendor
void _exitFullscreen() {
    _callMethods(document, ['exitFullscreen', 'webkitExitFullscreen', 'mozCancelFullScreen', 'msExitFullscreen', 'oExitFullscreen']);
}

/// checks whether fullscreen is active by getting the corresponding property of each vendor
dynamic _getFullscreenElement() {
    return _getProperty(document, ['fullscreenElement', 'webkitFullscreenElement', 'mozFullScreenElement', 'msFullscreenElement', 'oFullscreenElement']);
}

/// calls the first matching method of a browser object
dynamic _callMethods(dynamic browserObject, List<String> methods) {
    JsObject js = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(browserObject);

    for (String method in methods) {
      if (js.hasProperty(method)) {
        return js.callMethod(method);
      }
    }

    return null;
}

/// retrieves the first matching property of a browser object
dynamic _getProperty(dynamic browserObject, List<String> properties) {
    JsObject js = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(browserObject);

    for (String property in properties) {
        if (js.hasProperty(property)) {
            return js[property];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```