# Request Fullscreen in Dart

Tags: dart

How does requestFullscreen in Dart works? I want enable Fullscreen-mode on mobile devices.

I wrote following Code. But it changes nothing.

```
 querySelector(".btn").onTouchEnd.listen((l) {
        var body = document.body;
        body.requestFullscreen();
  });
```

But it didn't worked.I'm becomming on click always same error `document.body.requestFullscreen is not a function`

Comment: Is the code even executed? Not sure touch events are supported, but I guess you'd get a compiler error already if `onTouchEnd` weren't supported. I'd still check twice the code is actually executed.

Comment: If I add somethig like `print("Hello world!")`, it will be executed. I tested it. But `requestFullscreen()` doesnt work (or my usage of it wrong)

Comment: Can you please try `document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();`

Comment: Is this in Chrome Android or some other browser/OS?

Comment: I tried Chrome/Mozilla on Android. 
>Can you please try `document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();` – same error

Comment: I'd create a bug report in github.com/dart-lang/sdk

Comment: Maybe you know, how to lock screen orientation?)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be something like https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-html/VideoElement/enterFullscreen.html, so you need to call it on your video element.

Edit: Oh, yes, there's also https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-html/Element/requestFullscreen.html -- that might be the one you want.

Edit2: Apparently, this has already been asked and answered, and needs a workaround: [How to request fullscreen in compiled dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714889/how-to-request-fullscreen-in-compiled-dart)